# Order list by parameter and position in second list

Tags: c#, linq

In my c# app I have list of custom objects:

```
obj a,b,c,d,i,f,j
a.id = 1;
b.id = 2;
c.id = 3;
d.id = 4;
i.id = 5;
f.id = 6;
j.id = 7;
var firstList = new List<obj> {a,b,c,d,i,f,j};
```

And I have second list of `int`'s

```
var secondList = new List<int> {5,6,2,1,3};
```

Items in `secondList` - this is id's from `firstList` in specific order. This list can include not all id's from `firstList` (in example not enough `4` and `7`)

My question: how I can sort my first list by parameter `id` and by scenario, described in `secondList`. 
If in `secondList` some ids is missed - add corresponding items of  `firstList` to the end of result list.

Unfortunatelly solution with multiple `OrderBy(...).ThenBy(...)` can't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var firstListDic = firstList.ToDictionary(o => o.id);
var secondListSet = new HashSet<int>(secondList);
var result = secondList.Select(i => firstListDic[i])
                       .Concat(firstList.Where(o => !secondListSet.Contains(o.id)))
                       .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be:

```
secondList.Union(firstList.Select(o => o.id))
          .Select(o => firstList.FirstOrDefault(k => k.id == o))
          .ToList();
```

If your **obj** class contains something like

```
class obj
{
    public int id;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return id.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then you can test this

```
var firstList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }
    .Select(o => new obj() {id = o}).ToList();
var secondList = new List<int> { 5, 6, 2, 1, 3 };
var thirdlist =
    secondList
    .Union(firstList.Select(o => o.id))
    .Select(o => firstList.FirstOrDefault(k => k.id == o))
    .ToList();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",thirdlist));
```